# $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(\log n)^n}{n^{\log n}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(\log n)^n}{n^{\log n}}$$

This limit is equal to $+\infty$ but I don't understand why. I know that every exponential function with a base greater than 1 grows to infinity faster than any polynomial. But is this true only for a fixed base exponential that doesn't depend on the variable?

Or is it that, approaching positive infinity, the function at the numerator behaves like $a^n, a > 1$ in terms of comparison with a polynomial?

Sorry if this is a silly question.

Comment: It's true that log(n) grows at a glacial pace. However, you cannot go as far as saying that $(log(n)) ^{n} \ $ behaves like $a^n .$. The former expression eventually grows faster than the latter.

Comment: Look at a graph of log(x). As x grows large, log(x) increases, but extremely (and increasingly) slowly. If we're in base 10, then log(10) = 1. log(1000) = 3. log(1000000) = 6. log(10^50) is only 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By taking the logarithm
$$\log\left(\frac{(\log n)^n}{n^{\log n}}\right)=n\log\log n-\log^2 n$$

and then rewriting
$$n\log\log n-\log^2 n= n\left(\log\log n-\frac{\log^2n }{n}\right)$$
In the parenthesis, the second term goes to $0$. What happens to the first?

Comment: The second term actually goes to $0$. However, the first does go to $\infty$ so this ends up being $\infty \cdot \infty = \infty$ which is the correct answer.

Comment: Yes, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score -2):

$6^{1000000} >> 1000000^6 \ $ because that's a lot of $6$'s

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: I think it's a bit unfair to downvote without saying why you're downvoting.

Comment: I think the down votes are because those are just two random numbers that you can't really make a consist reasoning out of.

Comment: They're clearly not random if we're working in logarithms base 10. I have let $n = 10^6 \ $ in the expression $ \frac{(\log n)^n}{n^{\log n}}$. Which one should be able to see is relevant because we are seeing what happens when n gets very large. If we're working in logarithms base 10, the next step we could do would be to increase n by 10, i.e. compare $n = 10^6$ to $n = 10^7$, which after a bit of manipulation, gets us the result, and although it's not a rigorous proof, I think it's good enough to see what's going on.

Comment: *when I say increase n by 10, I meant let's see what happens to 10n